# How to show first youtube video in iframe and other in thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, youtube

Hi I want to show only the first video in iframe while other in thumbnail.
Here is my code you can run it on localhost.If you have any solution then please reply me.

> index.php file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>youtube Channel Videos</title>
    <style>
        body{
        background: #f4f4f4;
        font-family: "Arial" sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #666;
        }
        #container{
        width: 800px;
        overflow: auto;
        margin: auto;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 15px;
        }
        .anc{
            padding: 2px 6px;
            background: #EFF7FF;
            color: #069;
            border: 1px solid #C2D9EF;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 1px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<!--     <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    // put your code here
    ?>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Youtube Videos</h1>
        <ul id="results">

        </ul>
        <div id="page" style="padding-top: 15px;padding-left: 42px;"></div>
    </div>

    <script>

    players = new Array();
//alert($("iframe.yt_players"));
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    var temp = $("iframe.yt_players");    
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        var t = new YT.Player($(temp[i]).attr('id'), {
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
        players.push(t);
    }
}

 window.onload = setTimeout(onYouTubeIframeAPIReady, 10000);


function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        var temp = event.target.a.src;
        var tempPlayers = $("iframe.yt_players");
        for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            if (players[i].a.src != temp) players[i].stopVideo();

        }
    }
}

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> script.js file

```
function tplawesome(template, data) {
    // initiate the result to the basic template
    res = template;
    // for each data key, replace the content of the brackets with the data
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        res = res.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g, function(match, j) { // some magic regex
            return data[i][j];
        });
    }
    return res;
}
var channelName= "TechGuyWeb";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",{
    part: 'contentDetails',
    forUsername: channelName,
    key:'AIzaSyBX94DoCYdtIwALVPfqSVar6izj3wCJ1M4'},
    function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data.items,function(i, item){        
        var pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
        //console.log(pid);     
        getVids(pid);
    });
    }
    );
//var pid="10thStreetPreschool";

//    function getvids(pid){
//  $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{
//  part: 'snippet',
//  maxResults: 10,
//  playlistId:pid,
//  key:'AIzaSyBX94DoCYdtIwALVPfqSVar6izj3wCJ1M4'},
//    function(data){
//  var output;
//  $.each(data.items,function(i, item){
//      console.log(data);
//      var v_id = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;    
//      //alert(item.snippet.resourceId.videoId);
//      //var video_title = item.snippet.title;
//      //output= '<li>'+video_title+'</li>';
//      $.get("item.html",function(data){
//      $('#results').append(tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title,"videoid":item.snippet.resourceId.videoId,"description":item.snippet.description}]));
//      getcount(v_id);
//      });
//      //$('#results').append(output);
//  });
//    }
//    );
//    }
function getVids(pid, pageToken){
        var data = {
          part: 'snippet',
          maxResults: 10,
          playlistId: pid,
          key: 'AIzaSyBX94DoCYdtIwALVPfqSVar6izj3wCJ1M4'
        }

        try{
          if(pageToken){
            data["pageToken"] = pageToken;
          }
        }catch(err){
        }

        $.get(
          "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", data,
          function(data){
            var output;
        $('#results').html("");
            $.each(data.items,function(i, item){
        console.log(data);
        var v_id = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
//      var total_results =data.pageInfo.totalResults;
//      console.log(total_results);

        $.get("item.html",function(data){
        $('#results').append(tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title,"videoid":item.snippet.resourceId.videoId,"description":item.snippet.description}]));
        getcount(v_id);
        });
        //$('#results').append(output);
    });
        $('#page').html("");
            try{
              if(data.prevPageToken){         
        $("#page").append('<span><a class="anc" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getVids(\'' + pid + '\', \'' + data.prevPageToken + '\');">&laquo; Previous<a/></span>');
              }
            }catch(err){
            }
    try{
              if(data.nextPageToken){         
         $("#page").append('<span><a class="anc" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getVids(\'' + pid + '\', \'' + data.nextPageToken + '\');">Next &raquo;<a/></span>');
        }
            }catch(err){
            }
          });
      }
    function getcount(v_id){
    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",{
    part: 'statistics',
    id: v_id,
    key:'AIzaSyBX94DoCYdtIwALVPfqSVar6izj3wCJ1M4'},
    function(data){
    $.each(data.items,function(i, item){

        var views = item.statistics.viewCount;
        //console.log(views);    
        $('#'+v_id).append(views);

    });
    }
    );
    }

});

function getVids(pid, pageToken){             
        var data = {
          part: 'snippet',
          maxResults: 10,
          playlistId: pid,
          key: 'AIzaSyBX94DoCYdtIwALVPfqSVar6izj3wCJ1M4'
        }

        try{
          if(pageToken){
            data["pageToken"] = pageToken;
          }
        }catch(err){
        }

        $.get(
          "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", data,
          function(data){
            var output;
        $('#results').html("");
            $.each(data.items,function(i, item){
        console.log(data);
        var v_id = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;    
        //alert(item.snippet.resourceId.videoId);
        //var video_title = item.snippet.title;
        //output= '<li>'+video_title+'</li>';
        $.get("item.html",function(data){
        $('#results').append(tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title,"videoid":item.snippet.resourceId.videoId,"description":item.snippet.description}]));
        getcount(v_id);
        });
        //$('#results').append(output);
    });
        $('#page').html("");
            try{
              if(data.prevPageToken){         
        $("#page").append('<span><a class="anc" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getVids(\'' + pid + '\', \'' + data.prevPageToken + '\');">&laquo; Previous<a/></span>');
              }
            }catch(err){
            }
    try{
              if(data.nextPageToken){         
         $("#page").append('<span><a class="anc" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getVids(\'' + pid + '\', \'' + data.nextPageToken + '\');">Next &raquo;<a/></span>');
        }
            }catch(err){
            }
          });

      }
      function getcount(v_id){
    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",{
    part: 'statistics',
    id: v_id,
    key:'AIzaSyBX94DoCYdtIwALVPfqSVar6izj3wCJ1M4'},
    function(data){
    $.each(data.items,function(i, item){

        var views = item.statistics.viewCount;
        console.log(views);  
        $('#'+v_id).append(views);

    });
    }
    );
    }
```

> item.html file

```
<div class="item" style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
<iframe id="player{{videoid}}" class="yt_players" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{videoid}}?rel=0&enablejsapi=1;showinfo=0;&wmode=Opaque" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div style="margin-bottom: -22px;margin-top: -20px;"><h2 style="font-size:18px;">{{title}}</h2></div>
<div style="margin-bottom: -18px;"><h5 style="font-size:16px;">{{description}}</h5> </div>
    <div><h5 style="font-size:14px;margin-top: -5px;">Total Views: <span id="{{videoid}}"></span></h5> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be more specific and post only the part of code which is relevant to your question.

Comment: okk i will take care of it have you got any solution for this problem